# how to name functions that return booleans

Tags: naming, typescript, boolean

I like the practice of naming boolean variables with a prefix like "is", "has", "should", or "can".

But what about the functions that produce those results?

Currently I'm using:

```
const isReadyForPublicProfile = checkWhetherIsReadyForPublicProfile(teacherOf);
const shouldWarnAboutProfileChangingToPrivate =
    checkWhetherShouldWarnAboutProfileChangingToPrivate(isDirty, teacherOf);
```

What is the best practice for naming the function?

Answer (score 4):

There is no universal practice to name functions that return Booleans, because such Boolean results can have a broad variety of purposes.  The main naming rules are to use names that reveal the intentions, be consistent, and avoid names that are too long.

Some authors proposed popular recommendations:

- Steve McDonnel's popular [Code Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Complete) suggests the list that you have "is", "has", "should", or "can", but for variable names. You can easily extend it to method names, since R.C. Martin recommends to use a verb or a verbal phrase for method names, which is not incompatible with those prefixes.
- Stephen Colebourne, a contributing expert to the Java JSR standardization process, proposed a list for method prefixes in a [2011 article](https://blog.joda.org/2011/08/common-java-method-names.html) in which there is only `is` that has an explanation referring to Boolean results. By the way, his list made it into the official [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html)

Interestingly,  in view of the prefix in the above list, your naming would be ambiguous:

> check:  Checks if something is true, throwing an exception if it is not true. Example foo.checkValid().

Get rid of the `checkWhether` prefix.  You could for the variable even [get rid of the prefix](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/naming-boolean-variables-prefixes-df973d7d7ec3):

```
const readyForPublicProfile = isReadyForPublicProfile(teacherOf);
if(readyForPublicProfile) {
    publish(); 
}
```

Comment: In TypeScript, I strongly prefer prefixing boolean variables with a prefix like "is", "has", "should", or "can". It's nice to know without needing to hover or explore anything that the variable is boolean. And the guideline of "use a a verb or a verbal phrase for method names" is something that makes sense to me, which is why I named the functions the way I did. +1 for your answer. I appreciate the thoughts and links!

Answer (score 1):

Your function names are very long, and the “checkWhether” doesn’t contribute anything of value. So the function names should be “isReadyForPublicProfile” and “shouldWarnAboutProfileChangingToPrivate”.

Comment: In TypeScript, I can't have functions that are the same name as the constant whose value I'm assigning as the result of the function. I don't mind long function names if it is necessary for clarity.

Comment: @Ryan: If you cannot have both, then keep function names starting with "is" or "should" and use other names for local variables instead. E.g. you can use abbreviations for local variables, like "isReady" and "shouldWarn", because their meaning is easily understandable from the context.

Comment: `is, has, should` and `can` generates cognitive burden. I know, because I used them too. While I also like them (overall for methods), short and concise var names are going to be always superior because they won't make devs fall asleep. So, in Typescript or in any other language `ready` or `publishable` are fairly better than `isReadyForPublicProfile` because the boolean var's scope is (ideally) local and whatever they are ready for is implicit in the scope.

Comment: @Laiv, for me "is", "has", "should", "can" have very, very specific meanings that shouldn't be removed.

Comment: For example, `publicProfile` is a misleading variable name if what it really means is `isProfilePublic`. At first glance (before seeing that it was boolean), my guess was that `publicProfile` meant that there were multiple versions of the profile, and this was the public version of it. _That's_ cognitive load.

Comment: @Ryan: Coming up with variations just because you want to avoid collisions means that you are setting yourself up for a guessing game of "what variation did I use here?" for the maintenance phase. Don't. Pick a name that unambiguously describes the purpose, and pick the most obvious name that someone can reasonably think of/understand when they maintain this code.

Comment: There isn't a single convention that makes sense nor one that should be used in every case. Optimize for readability. For example, `canActivate: (path: string) => boolean` is expressive and clear yet so is `active: (path: string) => boolean`.